# namedtuple._replace() doesn't work as described in the documentation

Tags: python, namedtuple

I was having trouble implementing `namedtuple._replace()`, so I copied the code right off of the documentation:

```
Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x,y')

p = Point(x=11, y=22)

p._replace(x=33)

print p
```

and I got:

```
Point(x=11, y=22)
```

instead of:

```
Point(x=33, y=22)
```

as is shown in the doc.

I'm using Python 2.6 on Windows 7

What's going on?

Comment: This works the same way as str.replace() does.  Both strings and named tuples are immutable, so their replacement methods produce *new* values while leaving the old value unchanged.  The solution to your problem is to save the new result to a variable.

Comment: Great question if for no other reason than that everybody wanting to "modify" a namedtuple is going to trip over this at some point.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Yes it does, it works exactly as documented.

`._replace` *returns* a new namedtuple, it does not modify the original, so you need to write this:

```
p = p._replace(x=33)
```

See here: [somenamedtuple._replace(kwargs)](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace) for more information.

Comment: Good thing to note from the documentation: I was wary of using an underscore-prefixed method since that's typically done to indicate [the method is private](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables). However in this case it's done to avoid conflicts with the `namedtuple`'s fields (which might include something called `replace`), so this is safe to use. There's an `._asdict()` method which works similarly.

Answer (score 21):

A tuple is immutable. `_replace()` returns a new tuple with your modifications:

```
p = p._replace(x=33)
```

Answer (score 13):

[`namedtuple._replace()`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace) returns a new tuple; the original is unchanged.

Answer (score 6):

It looks to me as if namedtuple is immutable, like its forebear, tuple.

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x,y')
>>>
>>> p = Point(x=11, y=22)
>>>
>>> p._replace(x=33)
Point(x=33, y=22)
>>> print(p)
Point(x=11, y=22)
>>> p = p._replace(x=33)
>>> print(p)
Point(x=33, y=22)
```

`NamedTuple._replace` returns a new `NamedTuple` of the same type but with values changed.

Comment: FWIW, the method name was inspired by str.replace() which has a remarkably similar pattern of use :-) ``s='the quick brown fox'; s=s.replace('quick', 'slow')``

Answer (score 1):

But YES, you are right: in the 'official' documentation, they forgot to assign the replaced tuple to a variable: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=collections#collections.namedtuple

```
p._replace(x=33)
```

instead of

```
p1 = p._replace(x33)
```

Comment: The official documentation shows that when you run `p._replace(x=33)` on the interactive Python prompt, it outputs the new tuple to screen. They didn't forget anything, this is perfectly fine interactive use. The next line shows a more complex bit of code where the return value is assigned to something.